# Where can i find the IPA sounds with example words and their pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa

I want to learn the IPA but all the websites i found are incomplete. For example: it has the sounds chart but doesn't have example words (with pronunciation), and sometimes it doesn't even have the sounds of the symbols.

Do you know any resource that fits those requirements? (Preferably with american english pronunciations)

Comment: Here's a web tool, complete with IPA, common term, audio and corresponding images:
 [vowels](https://elt.oup.com/student/englishfile/elementary/c_pronunciation/pronunciation01?cc=vn&selLanguage=en) and [consonants](https://elt.oup.com/student/englishfile/elementary/c_pronunciation/pronunciation03?cc=vn&selLanguage=en) and [dipthongs](https://elt.oup.com/student/englishfile/elementary/c_pronunciation/pronunciation02?cc=vn&selLanguage=en)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Why is that not an answer?

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't have the physical time to post it as a fully fledged answer. It's there for anyone to "take".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wikipedia page that pulls together almost everything you want, and for much more than just American English:

[IPA chart for English dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects)

It lists all the lexical sets for English vowels for many major dialects of English, showing where individual dialects merge or distinguish within some of these sets.

But IPA, much more consistent than English spelling or the pronunciation guides given by dictionaries, just doesn't do what actual hearing does. For that, use

[Forvo](https://forvo.com/search/)

to check individual words, what they really sound like in reality. IT is not organized by lexical set or dialect, just by the official spelling of the word and whatever person randomly decided to pronounce the word (with a geographical tag for that person to give you an idea of accent).

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia Help:IPA/English site is very good. The example words don't have pronunciations, but they are so common you will know how to pronounce them all. The notes explain the few differences between American and British (and other) pronunciations. The site is at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English